# How to access "previous versions" of files in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, backup

Windows 7 had a feature where I could open the properties of a folder and access "Previous Versions" of files within that folder.

I no longer see this capability in Windows 8, and I have double-checked that I have protection turned "On" for my hard disks at the System Properties window.

Was this feature removed, and if so, what good is turning protection "On" for non-OS disks anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The "Previous Versions" feature was removed from Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848072(v=vs.85).aspx) because usage of the feature was low and negatively impacted system performance.

It has been replaced with [File History](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/how-use-file-history).

Turning protection on for non-OS disks is only useful for System Restore (e.g. if you choose to install software on non-OS disks).

Comment: Worth also noting that the Windows 8 "File History" feature only backs up personal folders such as Documents, Music etc. and can't be applied to save previous versions of all files on the hard drive like the Windows 7 "Previous Versions" feature did.